# array grouping which contains same fields

Tags: php, database, arrays, model, grouping

I have an array which contains following values.

```
array(
'dates' => array(
    (int) 0 => '2013-04-22',
    (int) 1 => '2013-04-23',
),
'publisherName' => array(
    (int) 0 => 'Comp1',
    (int) 1 => 'Comp2',
),
'loaded' => array(
    (int) 0 => (int) 2189,
    (int) 1 => (int) 37,
),
'clicks' => array(
    (int) 0 => (int) 0,
    (int) 1 => (int) 0,
),
'ctr' => array(
    (int) 0 => (int) 0,
    (int) 1 => (int) 0,
)
)
```

What I want to produce is getting company based data on different dates like the array below.

How am I able to create an array which is like;

```
array (
    '2013-04-22'=>array(
        'publisherName'=>'Comp1',
        'loaded'=>2189,
        'clicks'=>0,
        'ctr'=>0),
    '2013-04-23'=>array(
        'publisherName'=>'Comp2',
        'loaded'=>37,
        'clicks'=>0,
        'ctr'=>0)
    ...
)
```

Which contains daily stats but which comes from `publishername` field.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your result array has no relation to the original arrays, please be more clear. Even though I can guess what't you're saying doesn't mean that I'm right.

Comment: @Jonast92 changed the field name 'name' to what is in original 'publishername'

Comment: @Jonast92 now the array that I want to produce is the same as the initial array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that doesn't rely on any keys, the only requirement is that `date` is the first array in your original array:

```
// $array is your original array
$dates = array_shift($array);

$output = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $a) {
  foreach ($a as $i => $v) {
    $output[$i][$k] = $v;
  }
} 
$output = array_combine($dates, $output);
```

Comment: When I run the code, I get following warning:array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

Comment: @canpoint do both parameters have an equal number of elements? you can't have 3 elements in the `$dates` array, and 4 in the `$output` array for example - http://codepad.viper-7.com/1so9du

Comment: I just tried it with my example array and it gives this warning, seems like they have same number of elements

Comment: @canpoint obviously they don't have the same number of elements, hence the warning

Comment: This is solved with the one that rely on keys is also okay for me. Can you also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689576/array-grouping-data-which-comes-from-db-model which contains same logic but I couldnt reac a point since morning.

Answer (score 1):

Let the initial array be $a and the desired array $b;
Code:

```
$b = array();
$count = 0;
foreach($a['dates'] as $date) {
    $b[$date] = array(
        'name' => $a['publisherName'][$count],
        'loaded'=> $a['loaded'][$count],
        'clicks'=> $a['clicks'][$count],
        'ctr'=> $a['ctr'][$count]
    );
    $count++;
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [2013-04-22] => Array
        (
            [name] => Comp1
            [loaded] => 2189
            [clicks] => 0
            [ctr] => 0
        )

    [2013-04-23] => Array
        (
            [name] => Comp2
            [loaded] => 37
            [clicks] => 0
            [ctr] => 0
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$data = $yourarray;
$new = array();
foreach($data['dates'] as $key=>$value) {
    $new[$value] = array('name'=>$data['publisherName'][$key],'loaded'=>$data['loaded'][$key],'clicks'=>$data['clicks'][$key],'ctr'=>$data['ctr'][$key]);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($new);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_arr = your array;
$finalArray = array();
foreach($new_arr['dates'] as $key => $value){
    $finalArray[$value] = array(
        'publisherName'=>$new_arr['publisherName'][$key],
        'loaded'=>$new_arr['loaded'][$key],
        'clicks'=>$new_arr['clicks'][$key],
        'ctr'=>$new_arr['ctr'][$key]
    );
}
```

Output :

```
Array
(
[2013-04-22] => Array
    (
    [publisherName] => Comp1
    [loaded] => 2189
    [clicks] => 0
    [ctr] => 0
)

[2013-04-23] => Array
    (
    [publisherName] => Comp2
    [loaded] => 37
    [clicks] => 0
    [ctr] => 0
)
```

)

Comment: this is not what he wanted to do. check the output of your $new_arr

Comment: Ooops my bad. I just noticed my mistake.. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($data['dates'] as $key=>$value) {
    $new[$value] = array('name'=>$data['publisherName'][$key],'loaded'=>$data['loaded'][$key],'clicks'=>$data['clicks'][$key],'ctr'=>$data['ctr'][$key]);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArr);
```